# Is that possible that we use spring actuator inside a spring MVC application and then change the managenement endpoint base path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have successfully created Spring Actuator endpoints by injecting beans provided by Spring Actuator dependencies. But now I need to change the base path of the management endpoints to other endpoint pattern "/internal", But this is a Spring MVC application, I can't directly do it using application.properties file as we do in original spring boot appliation (`management.endpoints.web.base-path=/custom-ednpoint`). Is this operation permissible for Actuator running spring MVC app?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@ComponentScan({"com.content.server"})
public class ActuatorConfiguration {

@Bean
@Autowired
public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(
    Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints
) {
 return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public EndpointMvcAdapter infoMvcEndPoint(InfoEndpoint delegate) {
 return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public EndpointMvcAdapter beansEndPoint(BeansEndpoint delegate) {
 return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public EndpointMvcAdapter dumpEndPoint(DumpEndpoint delegate) {
return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
}

 }
```

Comment: What beans did you inject? Please, share the excerpts of the config with the Actuator beans.

Comment: @madhead I have added the code snipet for bean injection